# Unity Game with Voice Chat

Tags: unity, unity-networking, voice

Have been working on a Poker game, it is network based and instead of launching game instance on server. I have managed everything via www class and on server created PHP API.

Now PHP is taking care of tables and rounds and then updating MySQL DB, and clients (mobile devices) just communicate to PHP over http. There are multiple tables and maximum of 5 players can sit on the table.

I need to implement voice chat between the players of the room, there can be visitors in the room as well. so 5 people are playing but may be 10, 20 people are watching them play.

What are my options on implementing voice messages? I am not using any Photon or UNET or any other server game instance.

Thank you

Comment: This looks like a "which technology should I use" question, which is not considered on-topic for our Q&A here. You can try asking on [chat] or a discussion forum, or see if you can edit your question to outline the specific problem you're trying to solve with an existing chat technology.